# How to fill a numpy array with a gradient with a vectorized code?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Two numpy arrays have to be filled as follow:

```
[0 1 2]
 [0 1 2]
 [0 1 2]
 [0 1 2]
 [0 1 2]]

[[0 0 0]
 [1 1 1]
 [2 2 2]
 [3 3 3]
 [4 4 4]]
```

Or [image]

A first idea was:

```
ax=np.zeros((5,3),np.int16)
ay=np.zeros((5,3),np.int16)

for j in range(0,3):
    for i in range(0,5):
        ax[i,j]=j#filling ax with x=col
        ay[i,j]=i#filling ay with y values y=li
```

A second idea was:

```
bx = np.zeros((5,3),np.int16)
by = np.zeros((5,3),np.int16)

for j in range(3):
    bx[:,j]=j

for i in range(5):
    by[i,:]=i
```

I am sure there's a better way, which one?
Thanks
jp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think using `numpy.tile` might be better:

```
In [422]: np.tile((0,1,2), (5,1))
Out[422]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [0, 1, 2],
       [0, 1, 2],
       [0, 1, 2],
       [0, 1, 2]])

In [473]: tile(arange(5)[:,None], 3)
Out[473]: 
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 3],
       [4, 4, 4]])
```

**Time efficiency:**

for a small matrix of shape (5,3), the for-loop is faster:

```
In [490]: timeit np.tile((0,1,2), (5,1))
10000 loops, best of 3: 38.3 us per loop

In [491]: %%timeit
     ...: bx = np.zeros((5,3),np.int16)
     ...: for j in range(3):
     ...:     bx[:,j]=j
     ...: 
100000 loops, best of 3: 16.5 us per loop
```

but for a large matrix of shape (5, 1000), `tile` is faster:

```
In [488]: timeit n=1000; tile(xrange(n), (5,1))
1000 loops, best of 3: 313 us per loop

In [489]: %%timeit
     ...: n=1000
     ...: bx=zeros((5, n))
     ...: for j in range(n):
     ...:     bx[:,j]=j
     ...: 
100 loops, best of 3: 3.97 ms per loop
```

Anyway, `tile` makes code cleaner.

Comment: Great!  How to timeit ?